# receive values of elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to print the value of the button clicked inside a group of buttons, as it is, the alert is triggered for all the buttons, but how do I know which button was selected? ^
Is there a smart way to know which was the last active button and get the value of it?

```css
window.onload = function(){

  $('#page-buttons').on('click', function() {
    alert('value of button clicked');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h1> Python</h1>
            <p id="cont">blabla</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="page-content" class="page-content">
          <div class="btn-group" id="page-buttons">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  value="first" >First</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  value="last" >Last</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</head>
</html>
```

Sorry for my bad english, i hope it has been clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.target` represents the clicked element, so you can check the `.val()` of `e.target`. Also note that duplicate IDs inside a single document is **invalid HTML** - stick with just the classes instead.

```js
$('#page-buttons').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log($(e.target).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h1> Python</h1>
        <p id="cont">blabla</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="page-content" class="page-content">
      <div class="btn-group" id="page-buttons">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="first">First</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="last">Last</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another way would be to attach the listeners to the buttons themselves, in which case you can use `this` to refer to the clicked button (the element the listener was attached to):

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h1> Python</h1>
        <p id="cont">blabla</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="page-content" class="page-content">
      <div class="btn-group" id="page-buttons">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="first">First</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="last">Last</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```